# Algorithm for progressive matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, fortran

I want to construct a matrix like so:

```
[ 0 1 2 3 4 5 ....
  1 2 3 4 5 6 ....
  2 3 4 5 6 7 ....
  3 4 5 6 7 8 ....
  4 5 6 7 8 9 ....
  5 6 7 8 9 10 ... ] etc
```

The main goal is to use the algorithm to put to the power the elements of an already existing matrix.

I am programming in Fortran, and I used the following code but it's not working:

```
do i = 1, m+1
  do j = 1, m+1
    do while ( w < 2*m )
      if ( i > j ) then
        ma(i,j) = 0
      else 
        w = i-1
        ma(i, j) = w
        w = w +1 
      end if
    end do
  end do
end do
```

Comment: I've stolen the C++ and matlab tags because I couldn't see the relationship.

Comment: Sounds to me that you want to put `i+j-2` into each cell?

Comment: What does it mean "it's not working"? Never say this, it does not tell us anything useful. Tell us what happens. Error messages? Which ones? Wrong results? How exactly wrong? See also [tour] and [ask].

Comment: I wonder if this is an *X-Y problem*.  Is it necessary to construct and store what seems likely to be an array which is not updated ?  Will looking up `ma(m,n)` be any faster than a call to a function defined as `ma(m,n) = m+n-2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, I managed to do it using the following code:

```
do i = 1, m+1
  w = i-1
  do j = 1, m+1
    ma(i, j) = u**w
    w = w+1
  end do
end do
```

I would like to state that i'm using Fortran 90 and only 90 because of my circumstances, otherwise I would've went with c++, (university life !!).

Please note that I used the desired series to put to the power the elements of the matrix.

Finally, I noticed some "complex" answers maybe, or maybe I'm just a beginner, but i would really love to learn if there are some rules and or dos and don'ts and or advice to get better at coding ( scientific code, not development code).

Thank you very much for the feed back, and waiting for any responses.

Comment: Please do take the Welcome [tour] I already linked. You will find out how to accept the answer that solved your problem a and other very useful info, like what an answer should and should not contain. Please use capital letters at the start of each sentence. Do not accept tips and dos and don'ts here, this is not a discussion forum, but a Question/Answer site that works in a specific way. Please do really take the [tour] to find out about it.

Comment: Being very honest, your answer achieves the desired result in a rather "convoluted" way compared to the other answers presented already. There is no much sense in having an auxiliary variable `w` that you increment by yourself each iteration when you have auto-increment with the do loop. If you remove it, you fall-back into one of the simpler answers that were presented.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use an implied-do in the array constructor syntax, possibly initialized in the same declaration:

```
integer, parameter :: n = 10, m = 5
integer :: i, j
integer :: ma(m,n) = reshape([((i+j, j=0, m-1), i=0, n-1)], [m,n])
```

The `[...]` syntax is posible in Fortran 2003 or higher. `(/.../)` should be used otherwise. My result with gfortran v7.1.1 is:

```
do i = 1, m
  print *, ma(i, :)
end do
```

---

```
$gfortran test.f90 -o main
$main
           0           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9
           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10
           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10          11
           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10          11          12
           4           5           6           7           8           9          10          11          12          13
```

Note: The initialization in the declaration would only be possible if `n` and `m` are constants (`parameter`). You could initialize it normally in the program body, otherwise, with the same implied-do syntax.
If you plan to read the values of `m` and `n` at runtime, you should make `ma` an allocatable array.

Answer (score 0):

While there is nothing wrong with Rodrigo's answer personally I think it much clearer to just use two loops

```
ian@eris:~/work/stackoverflow$ cat floyd.f90
Program yes
  Implicit None
  Integer, Parameter :: n = 5
  Integer, Dimension( 1:n, 1:n )  :: elp
  Integer :: base, offset
  Integer :: i, j
  Do i = 1, n
     base = i - 1
     Do j = 1, n
        offset = j - 1
        elp( j, i ) = base + offset
     End Do
  End Do
  Do j = 1, n
     Write( *, '( 1000( i3, 1x ) )' ) elp( j, : )
  End Do
End Program yes
ian@eris:~/work/stackoverflow$ gfortran -Wall -Wextra -std=f2003 -fcheck=all -O floyd.f90 -o genesis
ian@eris:~/work/stackoverflow$ ./genesis 
  0   1   2   3   4
  1   2   3   4   5
  2   3   4   5   6
  3   4   5   6   7
  4   5   6   7   8
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that others already made an algorithm that solves your problem. But i also bring another algorithm that works for a non-square matrix. NI is the number of columns of the matrix, and NJ is the number of lines. MAT is the matrix you want.

```
PROGRAM MATRIX    
IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER                     ::  I, J, NI, NJ
    INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE        ::  MAT(:,:)

    NI = 8
    NJ = 5

    ALLOCATE(MAT(NI,NJ))

    DO I = 1, NI
        MAT(I,1) = I-1
    ENDDO

    DO J = 2,NJ
        MAT(:,J) = MAT(:,J-1) + 1 
    ENDDO

    DO J = 1, NJ
        WRITE(*,'(8I3)') MAT(:,J)
    ENDDO
END PROGRAM
```